# Facing issue while calling a function "creditCardAmountBorrowedUpdation" in spring AOP

Tags: spring, aop

I am trying to call the functions "beforeApprovingCCTransactions" and "afterApprovingCCTransactions" while "creditCardAmountBorrowedUpdation(..)" is triggered. The function is not getting triggered. Below is the snippet from XML.

> File 1 :

```
package Logger;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class AuthorizeCCTransactionsLogs {

public void beforeApprovingCCTransactions() {
    System.out.println("Going to begin transaction for Credit Card");
}

public void afterApprovingCCTransactions() {
    System.out.println("Going to end transaction for Credit Card");
}
```

}

> File 2:

```
package AuthorizeCCTransactions;

public class CreditCardHelper {

public void creditCardAmountBorrowedUpdation(CreditCardBean retievedCreditCardBean , double amount ) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    retievedCreditCardBean.setAmount(retievedCreditCardBean.getAmount() + amount);
    CreditCardTransactionsDao creditCardTransactionsDao = new CreditCardTransactionsDao();
    creditCardTransactionsDao.update(retievedCreditCardBean);
}
}
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjDNC.png)

[XML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yMQr.png)

Comment: bhai pura code post karo

Comment: @saurabhkumar I have given the code

Comment: From the configuration xml shared you have not enabled spring aop. Add `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` to `context.xml` and retry.

Comment: If that does not work , please share a reproducible example with relevant classes. It is hard to go through images and do guess work to identify an issue.

Comment: @R.G Nor Working, check my git hub code.https://github.com/DipanjanSG/BankingApp/tree/master/src/main/java   . The context.xml file is in the path BankingApp/src/main/java/configs/context.xml

Comment: Spring AOP can only advice bean method calls. The code creates an [instance](https://github.com/DipanjanSG/BankingApp/blob/master/src/main/java/BusinessLogic/AuthorizeCCTransactions.java#L82) of `CreditCardHelper` with `new` operator which is not a spring container managed bean. Configure the `CreditCardHelper` as a bean and  obtain the same from application context for AOP to work. Also the naming convention followed is not per java standards and [ContextBeans](https://github.com/DipanjanSG/BankingApp/blob/master/src/main/java/configs/ContextBeans.java) is not the correct method to follow.

Comment: Please refer the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-dependencies) for more details

Comment: @R.G Thanx a ton buddy , I hav created a bean for CreditCardHelper. Let me know what to do about the "ContextBeans" Naming convention.

Comment: @R.G Can you check this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910080/property-driverclassname-threw-exception-nested-exception-is-java-lang-nosuch